# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client | body.content undefined

Tags: javascript, json, express, post

Why am I getting this error message?

This is the only route via post.
As far as I can see there is no other place where a header is sent.

I also don't understand why body.content evaluates to undefined,even though an object is sent and the header is set to json. By the way, the body parser or app.use(bodyParser.json()) didn't do anything.

"express": "^4.17.3"

I am thankful for help

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/api/persons/", (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  //if body has no data return here
  console.log(body.content);
  if (!body.content) {
    return res.status(400).end().json({ error: "missing content" });
  }
//generate entry in list
  const person = {
    number: body.number,
    name: body.name,
    id: generateID(),
  };
  persons = persons.concat(person);
  res.json(person);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.end` terminates the response. If you call `.end`, you can't send anything afterwards. Just remove that part and call .`json` to send the data to the client, without killing the response in the middle.

```
  if (!body.content) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "missing content" });
  }
```

Comment: Ok thank you, this was very useful. The only problem that remain, is that all objects evaluate to undefined which triggers the return-statement .

Comment: You mean `body.content` doesn't exist? Sounds like you need to look at what's sending the request and make it have a `.content` property